# How to insert/embed images in dynamically generated MS Excel file using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to export a report to Excel file using PHP i.e. on the fly. I am actually getting data from MySQL and presenting it in HTML tables.

I am able to export all this data into Excel file format, except images. I can't point the image source to an absolute URL, because this file also needs to work off-line.

Is there any way I can embed/insert images into this Excel file without using any library i.e. only PHP code or library which doesn't require PEAR/PECL extensions. I am using LAMP stack, so COM is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your reasoning is for not using PEAR, but there is a modified version ([PHP Excel Creator library](http://pizzaseo.com/php-excel-creator-class)) of PEAR [Spreadsheet Excel Writer](http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer) which does not have any dependencies on the rest of PEAR.

I know that the original PEAR version has a method [Worksheet::insertBitmap()](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.fileformats.spreadsheet-excel-writer.spreadsheet-excel-writer-worksheet.insertbitmap.php) . You would need to convert the images to bitmap if they aren't already (maybe using GD
in PHP)

If you are on Windows and have decent access to the server you could also try using COM to talk to Excel and generate the file that way.